# Namespace and interface with autoloading

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a folder structure like

```
-Factory
    -Car
        -Model.php
        -Model
            -Nano.php
```

Model.php

```
namespace Factory\Car\Model;
interface Model{
    public function build();
}
```

Nano.php

```
namespace Factory\Car\Model\Nano;
Class Nano implements \Factory\Car\Model{
    public function build(){
        echo "Buid a Nano";
    }
}
```

I am not able to include interface in my file

I am getting following error:

```
Interface 'Factory\Car\Model' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
namespace Factory\Car;
interface Model{
    public function build();
}
```

See [namespaces manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nested.php)